# Please assist to recover data after unsuccessfull upgrade to 12.04

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, files, data-recovery

Now my ubuntu shows the loading screen and doesn't load any further. I made a live cd and booted from it but I can't explore the needed files. I read that the partition with the installation has to be mounted but I'm not sure. Please help because my information is very important to me. 10x in advance.

Comment: in d:, now i found a directory called ubuntu there...

Answer (score 0):

First of all find out which partition you have your data on. For doing this, you can boot into live, type in "sudo fdisk -l" which will show you all your partitions, try mounting them one by one till you find out which partition has your data, and once you have found out that partition, you can copy tour data from there.

Comment: I see 3 partitions. They are all mounted and my installation isn't on any of them. I made that installation under Windows...

Comment: You got into live and you saw your partitions already mounted? That is not possible. You used wubi to install 12.04?

Comment: I used wubi to install 11.x and upgraded from the update manager(but my pc restarted and now ubuntu doesnt start). Im in live now and i see 3 partitions mounted (c:, d:, and system reserved). with sudo fdisk -l terminal lists 3 partitions.

Comment: Okay. Those are not mounted but are just here. :) There must be a partition corresponding to c: and d: like /dev/sda2 or something of the sort. Identify that and mount it using "mount /dev/sda2 /mnt". Go to /mnt and see if the files you require are there.

Comment: Mount is denied because the NTFS volume is already exclusively opened.
The volume may be already mounted, or another software may use it which
could be identified for example by the help of the 'fuser' command.

Comment: Just simply type in "mount" and see if the partitions are already mounted somewhere.

Comment: /dev/sda1 on /media/System Reserved type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)
/dev/sda2 on /media/1A9E35B49E3588F1 type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)
/dev/sda3 on /media/66CC2BC0CC2B88FF type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)

Comment: Cool. Go to /media/1A... and /media/66... using "cd" and check the files there.

Comment: 1A9E... is my C: , 
66CC... is my D: :(

Comment: Yes. The point is, you had your previous ubuntu installed inside windows right? So the files that you saved must be somewhere inside there itself. Why not try, ummm... "find /media/1A.. -iname Ubuntu"?

Comment: doesn't find anything

Comment: Where did you make the partition that you installed your older Ubuntu to?